# Shift ulong from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, bit-shift, ulong

I am converting application from C to C# now I met error in convert a shift with `ulong` value.

The original code in c++ is:

```
unsigned long long dat = (d >> dat_shift) & (0xffffffffffffffff >> (64 - data_bits_first_frame));
```

In C#, i think, it should be something like this:

```
long d = 1158552107947655168;
int dat_shift  = 8;
int data_bits_first_frame = 0;
ulong dat = (d >> dat_shift) & (0xffffffffffffffff >> (64 - data_bits_first_frame));
```

In runtime I get the error `CS0019 Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'ulong'`.

The reason is `0xffffffffffffffff`. Can you please help me to understand and solve the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show the types of all the variables so we can reproduce the issue. (We could guess, but it would be easier if we could just copy and paste.) (That's a surprising error message, given the two `ulong` parts.)

Comment: I kind of get a different error: https://ideone.com/Ol7WO3...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is:

> error CS0019: Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'long' and 'ulong'.

not `ulong` and `ulong`

To make it work `d` should be of type `ulong`:

```
ulong d = 1158552107947655168;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, but it's not working because in another part of code i have:
     int sid_shift  = 250;
     int sid_bits  = 4;
     uint sensorId = (uint)((d >> sid_shift) & (0xff >> (8 - sid_bits)));

If i change d from long to ulong i get there: error CS0019: Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'int'.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @Xabarass, if you want your result as `uint` than: `uint sensorId = (uint)(((uint)d >> sid_shift) & (0xff >> (8 - sid_bits)));` - cast `d` to `uint` (but it may be data loss)